# Eigenvector of a $1D$ Path/Grid Graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

Let $A$ be the $N\times N$ adjacency matrix of a 1D grid graph (also called path graph?) of size $N\times 1$. this can be seen as a discrete line of $N$ connected vertices:
[image: Example of a 1D grid]

I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ can be represented as:
\begin{equation}
    \lambda_k=2\cos \left(\frac{\pi k}{N+1}\right)
\end{equation}
for $k=1,\dots,N$.

**What would be the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix $A$?**

$A$ is real and symmetric so I would expect to find a set of $N$ real orthonormal eigenvectors.

**Edit**
By playing around, I found such a set: let $\vec{v}^{(k)}$ be the eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Then we have:
\begin{equation}
v_j^{(k)}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{N+1}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi j k}{N+1}\right)
\end{equation}
satisfying the orthonormal relations: $\sum_j v_j^{(k)}v_j^{(l)}=\delta_{kl}$.

Is there any intuitive explanation behind this?
If we had added weights to our graph, would the eigensystem be preserved up to some proportional term per node?

Comment: You did not misunderstand: there was a mistake in my formula, sorry! the denominator should be $N+1$ and not $N$, I fixed it.